# group by day in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, group-by

I have documents as the below in mongodb     `{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f956dee76ddb26752026e8f"), "page" : "home",  "visited" : ISOdate(23/02/2013) },  { "_id" : ObjectId("4f956dee76ddb26752026e8f"), "page" : "home",  "visited" : ISOdate(24/02/2013) },  { "_id" : ObjectId("4f956dee76ddb26752026e8f"), "page" : "home",  "visited" : ISOdate(24/02/2013) } , { "_id" : ObjectId("4f956dee76ddb26752026e8f"), "page" : "home",  "visited" : ISOdate(25/02/2013) }`   I want to get the day along with the count in mongodb using nodejs.  It should return:  `day: 23/02/2013, count:1 ,    day: 24/02/2013, count:2  ,day: 25/02/2013, count:1`.the result should be sorted in day so 23rd is first 24th is second and 25th is third. There are lots of entries around 1 million .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have duplicate ObjectIds in there so that is bad data.

Lastly you should be able to build a query using aggregates  something like this: (assuming you are on mongodb 2.2 + ).

```
db.mytable.aggregate([ {$group : {_id:"$visited", total:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{visited:-1}}])
```

Comment: I had copy pasted the example data so no issue with that. But if i run the above query i get output as        {
        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-01T11:45:10Z"),
        "total" : 2
},
{
        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-06T13:11:37Z"),
        "total" : 1
},
{
        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-01T05:56:26Z"),
        "total" : 1
},
{
        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-01T11:55:47Z"),
        "total" : 1
},
{        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-06T12:32:40Z"),
        "total" : 2
}. But i require to group by day, so only one row for a day and as u can see in the output there are 2 entries for 1st march

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * group by day
 * @link https://gist.github.com/phnessu4/5636642
 * @param query document {key1:123,key2:456}
 */
var count_by_day = function(query){
    return db.action.group(
    {
        keyf: function(doc) {
            var date = new Date(doc.time);
            var dateKey = (date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate()+"/"+date.getFullYear();
            return {'date': dateKey};
        },
        cond:query,
        initial: {count:0},
        reduce: function(obj, prev) {
          prev.count++;
        }
    });
}

count_by_day({this:'is',the:'query'})
```

try this. i'm not sure your condition detail . you need write the query by yourself.

hope this can help you.